# How should cross site canonical meta links be placed? Should they be different per page and should they go on the canonical domain itself?

Tags: domains, url, duplicate-content, canonical-url, rel-canonical

I have a website available via `www.mydomain.com` that is also available via `svr7464z.vps.hostingcompanycom`. The content is 100% identical, it's a mirror.

I don't want search engines to know about `svr7464z.vps.hostingcompany.com` and probably they never will but just in case they do I want to avoid duplicate content issues.

Unfortunately, blocking the offending URL is not possible and neither are 301-redirects.

So it seems rel=canonical should come to my rescue, but I'm confused where to place it.

Do I have to place the tags only on the `svr7464z.vps.hostingcompanycom` pages or also on the pages available via the official domain `www.mydomain.com`?

Also, do the tags have to be different based on the page?

*For example:*

For: `http://svr7464z.vps.hostingcompany.com`

Tag: `link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mydomain.com"`

For: `http://svr7464z.vps.hostingcompany.com/about`

Tag: `link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mydomain.com/about"`

For: `http://svr7464z.vps.hostingcompany.com/contact`

Tag: `link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mydomain.com/contact"`

Comment: Why are 301 redirects out of the question?   Do you not have the ability to create a *.htaccess* file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canoninical tags do have to be different per page.  Pointing all your canonical tags at the home page is a [mistake that will lead to Google only indexing your home page](http://www.michaelwall.co.uk/seo/canonical-link-element-mistakes/).

You may place the canonical tag on either the alternate pages only, or on both the alternate and `www.mydomain.com` pages.   You may place the canonical tag on both versions because self referencing canonical tags are OK.   As [Google's Maile Ohye says](http://moz.com/blog/dispelling-a-persistent-rel-canonical-myth):

> Yes, it's absolutely okay to have a self-referential rel="canonical". It won't harm the system and additionally, by including a self-reference you better ensure that your mirrors have a rel=”canonical” to you.

Answer (score 1):

You place the `canonical` tag in the header of the pages on `svr7464z.vps.hostingcompanycom`.

So *why* place it at `svr7464z.vps.hostingcompanycom`? When Google (or another search engine) wants to crawl `svr7464z.vps.hostingcompanycom`, it sees the `canonical` tag and it's like 'Hey, I should crawl `www.mydomain.com`, not this website!'.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="www.mydomain.com" />
</head>
</html>
```

There's just one more thing I would like to add. You say:

> The content is 100% identical, it's a mirror.

But how can you be so sure? When a `VirtualHost` isn't used, `svr7464z.vps.hostingcompanycom` and `www.mydomain.com` are probably **the same website**, which is reached through those (^) two domain names.

Comment: Perfect, and would I place the same tag on ALL pages or `<link rel="canonical" href="www.mydomain.com" />` in the root and `<link rel="canonical" href="www.mydomain.com/about" />` for `http://vr7464z.vps.hostingcompanycom/about` ?

Comment: @WPRookie82 I don't understand your comment, rephrase please.

Comment: I edited my original post to explain better.

Comment: @WPRookie82 OK, thanks :) To be honest I'm not sure, hopefully someone else can answer that question.